# Page redirects on same page in laravel getting 302 found in network tab?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-302

I am working on larapay template from envato market for my project with xampp server. I will share my code on which I am working now. Actually I am stuck on installation part. I am able to complete my installation part, it creates db and all, it shows me message of success but its not redirecting on login page. It redirects on same installation page.

[image: message after successful installation]

But actually it goes to installation again.

My web.php:

```
Route::resource('/install', 'AccController',['only' => ['index', 'store']]);
```

AccController.php :

```
public function store(AccRequest $request){     

        $link = @mysqli_connect($request->input('hostname'), $request->input('mysql_username'), $request->input('mysql_password'));

        if (!$link)
            return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.connection_not_established'), 'status' => 'error']);

        mysqli_select_db($link,$request->input('mysql_database'));
        $count_table_query = mysqli_query($link,"show tables");
        $count_table = mysqli_num_rows($count_table_query);

        if (!is_file('../database/database.sql'))
            return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.database_file_not_found'), 'status' => 'error']);

        if($count_table)
            return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.table_already_exists'), 'status' => 'error']);

        $templine = '';
        $lines = file('../database/database.sql');
        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
                continue;
            $templine .= $line;
            if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
            {
                mysqli_query($link,$templine) or print('Error performing query \'<strong>' . $templine . '\': ' . mysql_error() . '<br /><br />');
                $templine = '';
            }   
        }

        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $default_role = config('constant.default_role');
        $default_customer_role = config('constant.default_customer_role');
        $default_staff_role = config('constant.default_staff_role');
        $default_department = config('constant.default_department');
        $default_designation = config('constant.default_designation');

        mysqli_query($link, "insert into roles(name,is_hidden,is_default) values('$default_role','1','0'),('$default_customer_role','0','1'),('$default_staff_role','0','0')");
        mysqli_query($link, "insert into departments(name,is_hidden) values('$default_department','1')");
        mysqli_query($link, "insert into designations(department_id,name,is_hidden) values('1','$default_designation',1)");
        mysqli_query($link, "insert into users(email,username,password,is_hidden,status) values('$email','$username','$password','1','active') ");
        mysqli_query($link, "insert into profiles(user_id,first_name,last_name,designation_id) values('1','$first_name','$last_name','1') ");   
        mysqli_query($link, "insert into role_user(user_id,role_id) values('1','1') ");

        envu([
            'DB_HOST' => $request->input('hostname'),
            'DB_NAME' => $request->input('mysql_database'),
            'DB_USERNAME' => $request->input('mysql_username'),
            'DB_PASSWORD' => $request->input('mysql_password')
            ]);
        //complete($purchase_code);
        $this->logActivity(['module' => 'application','activity' => 'installed']);
        return response()->json(['message' => trans('messages.installation').' '.trans('messages.completed'), 'status' => 'success','redirect' => '/login']);
    }
```

How to redirect this page on `login` rather than again on installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had named route of `/login` as login, try this:

```
return redirect('login')->with('message', trans('messages.installation').' '.trans('messages.completed'))->with('status', 'success');
```

The `json` function don't accept the redirect parameter as i know.

After that, you may access `message` from the `session`:

```
@if (session('message'))
    {{ session('message') }}
@endif
```

Comment: it didnt work for me. i even dont get messages of installation completed